# Convert this 0-1 knapsack recursive to top down?

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I have written a knapsack recursive function and trying to convert it into top down.

1. Is the recursive function correct?
2. Can you help me convert it to top down?

```py
# with memoization - assuming n constraint is 100 and size is 1000
t = [[-1] * 200 for i in range(200)]


def find_max_profit(final_arr, w_arr, v_arr, n):
      if not w_arr:
        return sum(final_arr)
      if sum(final_arr) + w_arr[0] > n:
        return sum(final_arr)

      if t[len(w_arr)][n] != -1:
        return t[len(w_arr)][n]

      t[len(w_arr)][n] = max(find_max_profit(final_arr + [v_arr[0]], w_arr[1:], v_arr[1:], n),
                           find_max_profit(final_arr, w_arr[1:], v_arr[1:], n))
      return t[len(w_arr)][n]
```

Comment: Please ignore the bold statement, this is the first time posting a question :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm afraid you may not get answers to this question: *Is the recursive function correct?* It appears you are trying to outsource your testing. Test the code yourself, and if it doesn't produce the output you expect, and you can't figure out why, *then* ask for specific help on that issue.

Comment: It does produce the output, so lets ignore that question :P would appreciate response to second one though